# does closing command line window stop an expo server

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-go

I'm developing an app using Expo. I know to close an expo server you press ctrl+c, but if I just close the command line window will the server close?

I closed CLI without using Ctrl+C to close the sever and am wondering if its still runninng.

Comment: yes it will close.

Comment: Unless the process is running as a daemon, it will close when you close the window. This is true for all processes.